# oracle 11g database and java 1.5 problem

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

```
            ^
x.vmesniki.frkws.X.runtime.XX_LiteralSerializer:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CombinedSerializer
location: class x.vmesniki.frkws.X.runtime.XX_LiteralSerializer
    private CombinedSerializer myns2_string__java_lang_String_String_Serializer;
            ^
x.vmesniki.frkws.X.runtime.XX_LiteralSerializer:45: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class InternalTypeMappingRegistry
location: class x.vmesniki.frkws.X.runtime.XX_LiteralSerializer
    public void initialize(InternalTypeMappingRegistry registry) throws Exception {
                           ^
x.vmesniki.frkws.X.runtime.XX_LiteralSerializer:50: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class XMLReader
location: class x.vmesniki.frkws.X.runtime.XX_LiteralSerializer
    public java.lang.Object doDeserialize(XMLReader reader,
                                          ^
```

when i try to load java in sql i get this errors. If DB is 10g then works but if is 11g not. What can be different? Google said that package is not installed in 11g database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the jar containing XMLReader and friends have not been loaded into Oracle yet.

Comment: I don't know.  Perhaps you should talk to the DBA and ask if the appropriate package was included when installing Oracle?